# MySql Server Fails with error code = 1265 after Upgrading 8.0.13 --> 8.0.15

Tags: mysql

After Upgrading from MySql 8.0.13 (compiled from sourcecode) to MySql 8.0.15, the MySql Server can not start.
Log:

```
2019-02-12T10:09:52.275336Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'INSERT INTO routines SELECT * FROM mysql.routines' failed with error code = 1265, error message = 'Daten abgeschnitten für Feld 'sql_mode' in Zeile 7'.
2019-02-12T10:09:52.302630Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-02-12T10:09:52.302856Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

"Daten abgeschnitten für Feld" means "Data truncated for field" - its a German version ...

Table checker does not find any errors - how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. On the old mysql 8.0.13 server I corrected the field SQL_MODE for one of the stored procedures, what happened to be too long.

> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;

I found some (old) stored procedures I did not need anymore, and the entries in field SQL_MODE of one of that stored procedures were too long. After deleting that stored procedure, starting the new 8.0.15 server and "mysql_upgrade" everything is fine, the server can now start without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all:

The command
`INSERT INTO routines SELECT * FROM mysql.routines`
had its data truncated for field `sql_mode` on line 7 of the SELECT.

So in the 7th row returned by `SELECT * FROM mysql.routines`,
the column `sql_mode` of table `routines` was defined as too small to receive
the value from the matching column of the table `mysql.routines`.

Comment: Thats somehow true - but consider that this table is usually not visible in MysqlAdmin and that this table is not defined by the administrator, but when setting up, or upgrading the MySQL Server. 
Also the field "SQL_MODE" is usually not visible when defining stored Procedures with MySQLAdmin. Also the INSERT INTO ... command is issued by the server and out of my control - I did not even find it in the sourcecode.